# Rapidminer Graph view suspected export bug?

Tags: export, rapidminer

As my question was remained unanswered in Rapidminer forum via this address :

[my original question](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,6256.msg21862.html#msg21862)

I would like to propose it here again, please inform me if by any chance you know the answer.

I have noticed no matter what type of extensions we use for getting  export (i.e. .pdf, .ps .jpg , etc), the export engine do like a screenshot of the current view instead of the whole output space, this has caused lots of issues for me exporting gigantic decision trees of my research.

Please someone advise me on this issue.

Best,

Amir

Comment: Anyone couldn't advise me ?!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **log operator** at the end of your process and configure it by the information you need. The log operator will save all results in a **text file**. Based on this file you can generate all your graphs at any time using **rapidminer or gnuplot**...
I find this way the best to save your time and memory space and also very easy to share in my opinion.